# Python input variable comma seperated, for loop

Tags: python

My Code:

```
exampleA= input("Give me an ExampleA\n") #hello
exampleB = input("Give me an ExampleAB\n") #<- here you should be able to write 50, 70, 80

for x in exampleA and exampleB:
    print("nice" + exampleA) #<- i get nicehello
    print("for" + exampleB) #
```

so i want for each element in exampleB
Another print, but I get this output

```
nicehello
for50,70,80,90,20
nicehello
for50,70,80,90,20
nicehello
for50,70,80,90,20
```

but I want

```
nicehello
for50
nicehello
for70
nicehello
for80
```

by the way I'm a beginner in python

Comment: Doing `for x in exampleA and exampleB:` shows a fundamental misunderstanding of `and` which is a *logical operator* and so it amounts to asking if both the expressions `"hello"` and `"50, 70, 80"` are true. In natural language that makes no sense whatever, but Python has rules for converting such things to `True` and `False`, and like most implicit type coercions, it holds surprises for novices. If you want to know more, google for "Python truthy", but for now a simpler rule is *don't use logical operators on strings (until you know what you are doing)*.

Answer (score 1):

Change code to in this way:

```
exampleA= input("Give me an ExampleA\n") #hello
exampleB = input("Give me an ExampleAB\n").split(',') #<- here you should be able to write 50, 70, 80

for x in exampleB:
    print("nice" + exampleA) #<- i get nicehello
    print("for" + x) #
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to split the string and then iterate over the elements of the string:

```
exampleA= input("Give me an ExampleA\n") #hello
exampleB = input("Give me an ExampleAB\n").split(',') #<- here you should be able to write "50, 70, 80")
for x in exampleB:
    print("nice" + exampleA) #<- i get nicehello
    print("for" + x) #<- so i want for each element in exampleB
```

Output:

```
Give me an ExampleA
Hello    
Give me an ExampleAB
12,23,34
niceHello
for12
niceHello
for23
niceHello
for34
```

Answer (score 0):

As you given :

```
for x in exampleA and exampleB:
  print("nice" , exampleA) #it always print nicehello
  print("for" , exampleB) #since exampleB is 2030405060 it just prints whole data
```

It doesn't splits it for splitting you should use variable 'x'

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
exampleA= input("Give me an ExampleA\n") #hello
exampleB = input("Give me an ExampleAB\n") #<- here you should be able to write "50, 70, 80")

for x in exampleB.split(','):
    print('nice',exampleA)
    print('for',x)
```

Result:

```
Give me an ExampleA
abcd
Give me an ExampleAB
1,2,3,4
nice abcd
for 1
nice abcd
for 2
nice abcd
for 3
nice abcd
for 4
```